# A simpler list of cases

Tags: python, list, if-statement, case-statement

I have to test many cases, but this solution is not very elegant:

```
if '22' in name:
    x = 'this'
elif '35' in name:
    x = 'that'
elif '2' in name:    # this case should be tested *after* the first one
    x = 'another'
elif '5' in name:
    x = 'one'
# and many other cases
```

Is there a way to do this sequence of cases with a list?

```
L = [['22', 'this'], ['35', 'that'], ['2', 'another'], ['5', 'one']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `next` to take the first value from a generator.

```
x = next((val for (num, val) in L if num in name), 'default value')
```

The first argument of `next` is the generator to consume, and the second is the default value if the generator is entirely consumed without producing a value.

Comment: Great solution! Is there a nice way to have a default case if no match is found, or do I need a `try` / `except StopIteration`?

Comment: If you don't want the StopIteration raised, you can use [`next` with a default argument.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next). No need for try-excepts here.

Comment: @Basj `next((val for (num, val) in L if num in name), 'default value')` would do nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called **looping**:

```
for cond, val in L:
    if cond in name:
        x = val
        break
```